# Cabal repl can't :load module in library

Tags: haskell, cabal

Hi I have the following modules in cabal file:

```
library task1-lib
    exposed-modules:
        Interpreter,
        Parser
    build-depends: 
        base ^>=4.14.3.0,
        containers,
        mtl,
        parsec
    ghc-options: -Wall -Werror -Wcompat -Widentities -Wincomplete-uni-patterns -Wincomplete-record-updates -Wno-unused-top-binds -Wno-orphans -Wno-type-defaults

    hs-source-dirs:   
        task1/lib
    default-language: Haskell2010

executable task1
    main-is:          Main.hs
    ghc-options: -Wall -Werror -Wcompat -Widentities -Wincomplete-uni-patterns -Wincomplete-record-updates -Wno-unused-top-binds -Wno-orphans -Wno-type-defaults

    build-depends:    
        base ^>=4.14.3.0
    hs-source-dirs:   task1
    default-language: Haskell2010
```

When I do:

```
cabal repl
...
GHCi, version 8.10.7: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 2] Compiling Interpreter      ( task1/lib/Interpreter.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 2] Compiling Parser           ( task1/lib/Parser.hs, interpreted )
Ok, two modules loaded.
> :l Parser
```

I get the following error:

```
<no location info>: error: [-Wmissing-home-modules, -Werror=missing-home-modules]
    These modules are needed for compilation but not listed in your .cabal file's other-modules: 
        Interpreter
```

### Question

What to do when I want to load a single file to experiment with the functions from that module in repl?

Also when I try the command `cabal repl task1-lib` the same happens.

### EDIT:

There is a possible workaround to modify the cabal in the following way, by adding the `-Wwarn=missing-home-modules` after the `-Werror`. This still applies the `-Werror` for all warnings instead of the `missing-home-modules` error that remains a warning and makes it possible to :load a module in repl then.

```
library task1-lib
    exposed-modules:
        Interpreter,
        Parser
    build-depends: 
        base ^>=4.14.3.0,
        containers,
        mtl,
        parsec
    ghc-options: -Wall -Werror -Wwarn=missing-home-modules -Wcompat -Widentities -Wincomplete-uni-patterns -Wincomplete-record-updates -Wno-unused-top-binds -Wno-orphans -Wno-type-defaults

    hs-source-dirs:   
        task1/lib
    default-language: Haskell2010

executable task1
    main-is:          Main.hs
    ghc-options: -Wall -Werror -Wcompat -Widentities -Wincomplete-uni-patterns -Wincomplete-record-updates -Wno-unused-top-binds -Wno-orphans -Wno-type-defaults

    build-depends:    
        base ^>=4.14.3.0
    hs-source-dirs:   task1
    default-language: Haskell2010
```

Comment: Does it work if you type `import Parser` instead of `:l Parser`?

Comment: Yup that works, there's no error in that case. However, that import enables only functions that are exported by the module, so I can't test not exported functions. When you :load a module you can call functions that are even not exported.

Comment: Hmm...The error says that the problem is that `Interpreter` isn't listed in the `other-modules` section - have you tried adding it there? If that doesn't work either then I'm not sure what the problem is. You could just temporarily remove the export declaration and let everything be exported.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I could repeat the modules in the `other-modules` but I haven't found such configuration in neither of repos I checked on github. So I'm wondering what is the proper solution here. Maybe someone else will have some insight into it.

Comment: I tried it myself and it's actually producing a **warning** not an error - you've turned on the `-Werror` flag which is promoting it to an error. So you could remove that flag. Also, I found [this](https://github.com/hdevtools/hdevtools/issues/88) - the warning seems to be a bug that you can ignore

Comment: Yep, you are right, I've seen that issue. But I want the `-Werror` have enabled. But I've found this issue from some repo https://github.com/jyp/dante/issues/60 and there is a workaround for this to have `-Wwarn=missing-home-modules` that makes only the `missing-home-modules` a warning and other warnings remain errors. So this is the right possible workaround I think.

Comment: I've just edited the question with a possible workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> import enables only functions that are exported by the module

Instead of unsing `:load` or `import`, try using `:module + *NameOfTheModule`.

According to the docs for [`:module`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-module-cmd):

> :module supports the * modifier on modules, which opens the full
> top-level scope of a module, rather than just its exports.

This can't be done with ordinary `import` declarations, which behave much like `import`s in regular Haskell programs.

Comment: Ou, I forgot to thank you. It works, thanks :)

Comment: I find that `:module ` not works in .ghci  :(

Comment: @luochen1990 Perhaps ghci is not aware of the package. If you are in a cabal project, try using `cabal repl` instead of ghci.